# Solr DIH with xml - command full-import is not extracting

Tags: lucene, apache-solr

I'm trying to index some wiki pages using Solr 7.0, but in the last step for that, the DataImportHandler apparently isn't extracting the data. I don't know what is happing cause any error is throwing.

When I call http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import two different behavior are noticeable.

The first response for my first request is.

    `{
        "responseHeader":{
            "status":0,
            "QTime":75
        },
        "initArgs":[
            "defaults",[
                "config","data-config.xml"
             ]
         ],
        "command":"full-import",
        "status":"idle",
        "importResponse":"",
        "statusMessages":{}
     }`

The second response when I just press enter again is.

    `{
        "responseHeader":{
            "status":0,
            "QTime":26
        },
        "initArgs":[
            "defaults",[
                "config","data-config.xml"
            ]
        ],
        "command":"full-import",
        "status":"idle",
        "importResponse":"",
        "statusMessages":{
            "Total Requests made to DataSource":"0",
            "Total Rows Fetched":"2",
            "Total Documents Processed":"0",
            "Total Documents Skipped":"0",
            "Full Dump Started":"2017-10-28 07:05:31",
            "":"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 
                documents.",
            "Committed":"2017-10-28 07:05:31",
            "Time taken":"0:0:0.449"
        }
    }`

As you can see in the second answer, the DIH founds 2 documents or rows. It's exactly the number of the document that I have in my test file `wiki.xml`. The problem is DIH isn't extracting as you may notice in `Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.`

Here is my Solr configuration: [git gist](https://gist.github.com/JEricFarias/b758023d020323caf19c27f01aa39a46)
I'm using Windows 10, Solr 7.0 and Lucene 7.0.

What I'm tried so far...

- One those data that I'm trying to extract is the "user", but there are some irregularities with it, for example, the `<contributor>` XML tag have some time two subtag `<username>`(the user nickname) and `<id>`(the user id) when a user has an account and some other times when the user doesn't have an account the `<contributor>` appears only with one subtag `<ip>`. So I just try to import the data without the "user" data.
- I'm just trying to get only the id and title. To that, I comment the other fields in `data-config.xml`.

No one those tests work.